# Apply function to values in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that calls a mapping API and returns longs and lats given unstructured address data. This works, and I can pass

```
address = "12 & 14 CHIN BEE AVENUE,, SINGAPORE 619937"
lat, lon = get_coordinates(api_key, address)
print(lat, lon)
```

and get a result like `1.3332439 103.7118193`

Before this I have a SQL Query that populates a dataframe with all the addresses that I want geocodes for. What would be the best way to apply the function to every value in the dataframe, and store the longs and lats in separate columns in the dataframe?

I have tried creating a brand new dataframe and use apply, but this runs an abnormally long time `df2 = df.apply(get_coordinates(api_key, df['DeliveryAddress']))`

I have also tried `df['coords'] = df['DeliveryAddress'].apply(get_coordinates(api_key, df['DeliveryAddress']))` based on this answer to a [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61652558/apply-function-to-dataframe-column) but I think the way I am passing parameters to the function is wrong. Please assist with pointing me in the right direction.

EDIT:

This is the code I am using at the moment, when passing doing a single address:

```
def get_coordinates(api_key, address):
    base_url = "http://someURL.net/REST/v1/Locations"
    params = {
        "query": address,
        "key": api_key
    }
    response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()
    data = response.json()
    coordinates = data["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["point"]["coordinates"]
    return coordinates

address = "12 & 14 CHIN BEE AVENUE,, SINGAPORE 619937"
lat, lon = get_coordinates(api_key, address)
print(lat, lon)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That code shouldn't work. You call `get_coordinates(api_key, df['DeliveryAddress'])` and then use its result to apply to the dataframe. But `get_address` doesn't work with a pandas Series (the column) does it?

Comment: How is get_coordinates implemented? Just guessing, but you are passing an api key which hints that you reauthenticate for each check. If so, you may want to work on get_coordinates.

Comment: Yes tdelaney, it will reauthenticate with each check. How can I do it better?

Answer (score 1):

`apply` applies a function and a non-changing set of parameters to each row in the Dataframe, or in your case since you only use a single column, to each value in a pandas Series.

The code has a bug where you *call* the `get_coordinates` function with a dataframe column and then attempt to use the result in the `apply` function. Instead, you want to give name name of the function and any unchanging parameters such as the api key. Pandas will call that function for each address.

Authentication is expensive, so you really want to break that out of the get_coordinates function. Authenticate once and use that authenticated connection in the `apply`. Following is pseudo-code because I don't know enough about your api, but the general flow is

```
def _get_coordinates(address, connection):
    """Convert an address to coorindates on given connection"""
    return connection.get_address(address)
    
def df_expand_addresses_to_coordinates(df, api_key):
    connection = connect and authenticate with api_key
    try:
        lat_long_series = df['DeliveryAddress'].apply(
                _get_coordinates, connection)
        df[['lat', 'long']] = pd.DataFrame(
                lat_long_series.to_list(), 
                index=lat_long_series.index)
    finally:
        connection.disconnect_and_close()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am stuck on this part: connection = connect and authenticate with api_key  I have edited my question to include the code II am currently using to authenticate. How can I amend that to do the connection like you said?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't know what your `get_coordinates` function works. My guess is that it authenticates, does some sort of API request and disconnects. You want to do the connect once, then do a bunch of API requests, then disconnect. So, reimplement the get_coordinates code to do htat. That's not something I can do for you.